# Negative one in the power of one third

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the problem with the first equation? I know the square root of negative one is negative one so how is the first line possible?

$$(-1)^{1/3}=(-1)^{2/6}=\sqrt[6]{-1}^2=1$$

$$(-1)^{1/3}=\sqrt[3]{-1}=-1$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to format your posts.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\sqrt[6]{(-1)^2}$ in the first displayed equation?  The rules of exponents apply to positive real numbers.

Comment: "I know the square root of negative one is negative one". Firstly, this is incorrect. $\sqrt{-1}=i \neq -1$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Points all out the bottleneck in this seemingly problematic relation. Rules of exponents apply to **positive** real numbers

Comment: $a^{m/n}=\sqrt[n]{a^m}$ is not universal rule, it has some applicability limits, my book says it is applicable for $a>0, \frac{m}{n}\in \mathbb{Q}$